# Programs that display maths symbols like this site to type a maths assignment

Tags: support, mathjax, editor

I am searching for a program that uses the same sort of language as this site that I can type up maths assignments on. I downloaded MikTex (once I installed it, the only program I could find was TeXworks), and copied and pasted a question that I posted on this site, then hit the 'play' button, but it came up with errors and I noticed that there were a heap of other 'scripts' to chose from which led me to believe it was not simply a copy and paste job.

I only know the rules that this site uses from this link [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Can someone recommend a program that I can type maths equations according to these rules and save as a pdf or something that I can print?

Comment: You might prefer LyX to LaTeX if you lack the experience with computers to actually Google "basic latex tutorial" and learn from there.

Comment: I use MikTeX with [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) on top for my editor. Install MikTeX first, then TeXnicCenter should grab all of the right links to your pdf program and MikTeX itself if you click through the install windows carefully. It is just my preference, but just about any LaTeX compiler should get you rolling.

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/).  From the website:

> We compile your project for you so you can see the results right away. There's no software to install, so you can start writing and collaborating instantly.
>
> Our real-time preview also makes it great for learning — you can see how your final project will look whilst you type.

Comment: List and a comparison of similar online tools at TeX.SE: [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3/9954).

Answer (score 5):

It is important to know that [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) and [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) are not the same thing: [What is the relation between Latex and MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/what-is-the-relation-between-latex-and-mathjax)

I think that if you will be writing math often, it is useful to learn LaTeX. (In particular, if you are going to write thesis which will contain enough math symbols, then LaTeX is probably a way to go.) And since you have learned about MathJax syntax, you would not start from scratch. There are many LaTeX tutorials available, see for example this list on TeX.SE: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) You can find at TeX.SE also some comparison of editors: [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

But if you are looking for something, where you can use more-or-less the same syntax as on this site (=[Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)+MathJax), you can try [StackEdit](http://stackedit.io/) see  [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question/) and [MathJax WYSIWYG Editor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/mathjax-wysiwyg-editor/). (Maybe you will find also other useful applications there.) It is worth mentioning that StackEdit does not offer you space to save your text. You would have to use it in combination with Google Drive or save your projects locally or something similar.)

Comment: This answer touches on a *very* important point: we don't use LaTeX on this site, but rather an odd combination of Markdown and MathJax.  This certainly affected my own transition to using a local LaTeX editor, rather than the "edit answer" boxes here.

Answer (score 2):

[LatexLab](http://docs.latexlab.org/) might be a good place to get started.  It's LaTeX, not MathJax, but it's on the web so you won't have to install anything. They have a basic article template set up automatically, so appropriately inserted copy pasting should work. (By the way, LatexLab is also a great collaboration tool, since coauthors can share a single document.)